# Punjab install twisted run error on python

Tags: python, strophe, twisted.web, punjab

I am tring to install punjab on python for bosh setup work with openfire and stropher js.

when i try to run `twistd -y punjab.tac` and i got below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 694, in run
    runApp(config)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 411, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 494, in createOrGetApplication
    application = getApplication(self.config, passphrase)
--- <exception caught here> ---   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 505, in getApplication
    application = service.loadApplication(filename, style, passphrase)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 390, in loadApplication
    application = sob.loadValueFromFile(filename, 'application', passphrase)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/persisted/sob.py", line 215, in loadValueFromFile
    exec fileObj in d, d   File "punjab.tac", line 7, in <module>
    from punjab.httpb  import Httpb, HttpbService   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/punjab/httpb.py", line 18, in <module>
    from session import make_session   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/punjab/session.py", line 20, in <module>
    from punjab import jabber exceptions.ImportError: cannot import name jabber

Failed to load application: cannot import name jabber
```

My python version 2.7 i installed just before few minutes but its continuously taking pythin2.6 library. I havn't more knowledge about python.

Help me..!!
Thanks in advance ...!!

Comment: In a shell, type "python -V". Which version do you see?

Comment: It's showing me Python 2.6.6.. Can you please know how to configure python 2.7 and how to overcome to this error related import jabber ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the default python version is 2.6, and it is running twistd for that version.

Run the program from the site-packages of Python 2.7: use `usr/lib/python2.7/site_package/twistd` instead of `twistd`. To make it more convenient for yourself, you can set an alias for twistd with Python 2.7 (twistd_27) to point to the right version as follows:

`alias twistd_27='<path to twistd>'`